# Why is my react component not updating with state updates?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a map app I built that requires some map icons to appear/disappear after a button press, but I can't figure out how to set it to re-render the component when I pass in a new sports property from it's parents component :

Parent loads component:

```
<SimpleMap sports=[default value and future values go here] />
```

Simple map component(simplified):

```
constructor(props) {
  (props);
  this.state = {
    events: [{venue: {lat: 2, lon: 1}}],
    sports: ["baseball", "football",  "paddle", "soccer", "boxing", "dart", "biking", "golf", "hockey", "inline-skating", "tennis", "volleyball", "skateboard", "kickball", "bowling", "pool", "ride", "hike", "ice-skating"]
  };
};

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.setState({events: [{venue: {lat: 2, lon: 1}}],
                  sports: nextProps.sports});
  console.log(nextProps.sports);
}

static defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 36.160338, lng: -86.778780},
  zoom: 12,
  sports: ["baseball", "football",  "paddle", "soccer", "boxing", "dart", "biking", "golf", "hockey", "inline-skating", "tennis", "volleyball", "skateboard", "kickball", "bowling", "pool", "ride", "hike", "ice-skating"],
};

makeMapEvents (insertProps) {
  fetch("./json/meetup.json").then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((response) => {
    /* eventually returns new events object based on insertProps */
    this.setState({events: response});
  }
};

componentDidMount () {
  this.makeMapEvents(this.state.sports);
  console.log("mounted", this.state.sports);
}
```

Eventually ends up here to map events from state:

```
<GoogleMap>
  {this.state.events.map((result) => {
     return (<Marker key={counter++} lat={result.venue.lat} lng={result.venue.lon} 
                sport={this.props.sport} data={result}/>);
  })}
</GoogleMap>
```

Comment: Where is the `counter` variable defined? Also, you should pretty much never use an index value as a `key` property in React. Always use a unique identifier for each loop-rendered component, otherwise, you may run into odd behaviors when items are removed or reordered.

Comment: It's defined elsewhere. I simplified it. It's just a number. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

React ES6 classes do not autobind `this` by default to non-react base member methods. Therefore, the context for `this` in your function `makeMapEvents` is not bound correctly. There are 2 ways to fix this:

Via ES7 property initializer:

```
makeMapEvents = (insertProps) => {
  fetch("./json/meetup.json").then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((response) => {
    /* eventually returns new events object based on insertProps */
    this.setState({events: response});
  })
};
```

Via binding in constructor:

```
constructor(props) {
  (props);
  this.state = {
    events: [{venue: {lat: 2, lon: 1}}],
    sports: ["baseball", "football",  "paddle", "soccer", "boxing", "dart", "biking", "golf", "hockey", "inline-skating", "tennis", "volleyball", "skateboard", "kickball", "bowling", "pool", "ride", "hike", "ice-skating"]
  };

  this.makeMapEvents = this.makeMapEvents.bind(this) // << important line


}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.then((response) => {
    this.setState({events: resp});
}
```

You take in parameter `response` then try to use `resp` which isnt the variable you want.

Comment: Sorry, they was a typo when I copied it over and removed unneeded code. It was correct originally and not the problem(the fetch ajax code worked fine).

Answer (score 1):

The probable cause is that your `makeMapEvents()` function doesn't provide the correct lexical value of `this` when calling `this.setState()` and as a result your code doesn't work. Change the `makeMapEvents()` function definition to use **Arrow function** (`() => {}`) and provide correct lexically bound value of this as:

```
makeMapEvents = (insertProps) => {
  fetch("./json/meetup.json").then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((response) => {
    this.setState({events: response});
  }); // <-- Typo here. The closing parenthesis is missing
};
```

Also there is a typo in your code wherein the closing parenthesis is missing as shown in comments above

Comment: This is Reactjs with es6 classes as the components. makeMapEvents = (insertProps) => { throws a syntax error

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up props and state in the component. sports should only be in props, it shouldn't be in state as it is being passed in from the parent component.

```
constructor(props) {
  (props);
  this.state = {
    events: [{venue: {lat: 2, lon: 1}}] <== removed sports here, it didn't belong
};

componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
  this.setState({events: [{venue: {lat: 2, lon: 1}}],
                  sports: nextProps.sports});
  console.log(nextProps.sports);
}

static defaultProps = {
  center: {lat: 36.160338, lng: -86.778780},
  zoom: 12,
  sports: ["baseball", "football",  "paddle", "soccer", "boxing", "dart", "biking", "golf", "hockey", "inline-skating", "tennis", "volleyball", "skateboard", "kickball", "bowling", "pool", "ride", "hike", "ice-skating"],
};

makeMapEvents (insertProps) {
  fetch("./json/meetup.json").then((response) => {
    return response.json()
  }).then((response) => {
    /* eventually returns new events object based on insertProps */
    this.setState({events: response});
  }
};

componentDidMount () {
  this.makeMapEvents(this.props.sports);  <== changed to props.sports
  console.log("mounted", this.props.sports); <== changed to props.sports
}
```