# How do I ensure context is updating properly for every component in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I am trying to use react hooks and context to create a scheduling app. The part that I am currently working on is using a "Task Creator" to add tasks to the schedule, which can be previewed above it in real time. I cannot get the tasks to add to the preview when they are added to the context. I have to refresh the page for new tasks to show in the preview.  I will list below the code links and things that Ive tried, that I couldn't make it work with. After trying all of those things there are a couple of things that stand out to me and I feel are important, but I cannot figure out how to proceed even knowing them.

-The tasks in the local storage updates immediately when I add them using the task creator

-The tasks don't stay added in the local storage if I delete a task currently in the local storage before reloading the page, I think this indicates that there is some sort of disconnect between the local storage being updated and the tasks in memory that are actually being used in memory - if this is the case I cannot figure out how to remedy it

-Tasks delete in real time on the schedule preview, the page does not need to be reloaded

The code that I think is the most relevant are the reducer, context, task creator, schedule preview and main (the parent of both task creator and schedule preview) - I think the issue is somewhere in there

---

Schedule Preview

```
    import React, { useContext, useEffect } from "react";
    import TaskBlock from "../taskblock";
    import ScheduleContextProvider, {
      ScheduleContext,
    } from "../../contexts/ScheduleContext";
    import Task from "../models/taskmodel";
    
    const SchedulePreview = (props) => {
      const { tasks } = useContext(ScheduleContext);
      console.log(tasks);
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="schedulepreviewcontainer">
            <ScheduleContextProvider value={tasks}>
              <div className="schedulepreview">
                {tasks.length
                  ? tasks.map((task) => {
                      return <TaskBlock tID={task.tID} key={task.tID} />;
                    })
                  : null}
              </div>
            </ScheduleContextProvider>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    };
    
    export default SchedulePreview;
```

Task Creator

```
    import React, { useEffect, useContext, useState } from "react";
    import { ScheduleContext } from "../../contexts/ScheduleContext";
    
    function TaskCreator(props) {
      const { tasks, dispatch } = useContext(ScheduleContext);
      const [taskName, setName] = useState("");
      const [startTime, setStartTime] = useState("");
      const [endTime, setEndTime] = useState("");
      const [taskNotes, setNotes] = useState("");
      const [subtasks, setSubtasks] = useState("");
      const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch({
          type: "ADD_TASK",
          task: {
            taskName,
            startTime,
            endTime,
            taskNotes,
            subtasks,
          },
        });
        setName("");
        setStartTime("");
        setEndTime("");
        setNotes("Notes: ");
        setSubtasks([]);
      };
    
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div id="taskcreator">
              <div className="lineup">
                <div>
                  <input
                    className="tasknameinput taskcreationinput"
                    placeholder="Task Name"
                    type="text"
                    value={taskName}
                    onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
                    required
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <label htmlFor="starttime"></label>
                  <input
                    className="taskcreationinput timeinput"
                    type="time"
                    name="starttime"
                    onChange={(e) => setStartTime(e.target.value)}
                    value={startTime}
                  />
                  <label htmlFor="endtime"></label>
                  <input
                    className="taskcreationinput timeinput"
                    type="time"
                    name="endtime"
                    onChange={(e) => setEndTime(e.target.value)}
                    value={endTime}
                  />
                </div>
                <div>
                  <div className="create list of subtasks"></div>
                  <div className="creater of subtasks">
                    <input
                      className="subtasknameinput taskcreationinput"
                      placeholder="Subtask Name"
                      type="text"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="secondpart">
                  <label className="switch" id="typeselector">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <span className="slider"></span>
                  </label>
                  indicator
                </div>
              </div>
              <textarea
                cols="28"
                rows="5"
                className="tasknotesinput taskcreationinput"
                onChange={(e) => setNotes(e.target.value)}
                value={taskNotes}
              ></textarea>
              <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Add" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    
    export default TaskCreator;
```

Main

```
    import React, { useContext } from "react";
    import CreationSidebar from "./creationsidebar";
    import SchedulePreview from "./schedulepreview";
    import TaskCreator from "./taskcreator";
    import BackHeader from "../backheader";
    import ScheduleContextProvider, {
      ScheduleContext,
    } from "../../contexts/ScheduleContext";
    
    function Main() {
      const { tasks, dispatch } = useContext(ScheduleContext);
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div className="doubler">
            <div>
              <CreationSidebar />
            </div>
            <div className="content">
              <ScheduleContextProvider>
                <BackHeader />
                <SchedulePreview props={tasks} />
                <TaskCreator props={tasks} />
              </ScheduleContextProvider>
            </div>
          </div>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }
    
    export default Main;
```

Schedule Reducer

```
    export const scheduleReducer = (state, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD_TASK":
          return [
            ...state,
            {
              taskName: action.task.taskName,
              tID: Math.random() * 900000,
              pID: 1,
              startTime: action.task.startTime,
              endTime: action.task.endTime,
              isComplete: false,
              taskNotes: action.task.taskNotes,
              subtasks: action.task.subtasks,
            },
          ];
        case "REMOVE_TASK":
          return state.filter((task) => task.tID !== action.tID);
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
```

Schedule Context

```
    
        import React, { createContext, useReducer, useEffect } from "react";
        import { scheduleReducer } from "../reducers/schedulereducer";
        import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
        
        export const ScheduleContext = createContext();
        
        const ScheduleContextProvider = (props) => {
          const [tasks, dispatch] = useReducer(scheduleReducer, [], () => {
            const localData = localStorage.getItem("tasks");
            return localData ? JSON.parse(localData) : [];
          });
          useEffect(() => {
            localStorage.setItem("tasks", JSON.stringify(tasks));
          }, [tasks]);
          return (
            <ScheduleContext.Provider value={{ tasks, dispatch }}>
              {props.children}
            </ScheduleContext.Provider>
          );
        };
        
        export default ScheduleContextProvider;
```

---

> The things I have tried include re-rendering only the preview when the
> reducer is called using the effect hook,  but that doesn't work for
> different reasons depending on how I tried to implement it,  these are
> some of the resources I used attempting that.
>
> https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html
> https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html
> https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html
> https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html
> https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html
>
> I have tried removing props from anything that state could be used for
> instead and also passing props to basically everything in the hopes
> that at some point they would change and the component would re-render
> with the new state.  I got these ideas from
> [Why is my react component not updating with state updates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38196017/why-is-my-react-component-not-updating-with-state-updates)
>
> after this I kind of started trying random things because I couldn't
> figure it out.
>
> I tried changing `ScheduleContextProvider` to
> `ScheduleContext.Provider` which didn't do anything (No error or
> anything just would never load)  I also tried added
> `ScheduleContext.Consumer` places but that didnt work either.
>
> I have also tried just calling the default reducer function to try to
> "refresh" the state whenever a task is created
>
> I recently learned about hooks and context and reducers from a
> tutorial on Youtube,  the code from which I was able to run perfectly
> fine prior to using hooks here.  I spent a lot of time comparing my
> code to the tutorial code
> (https://github.com/iamshaunjp/react-context-hooks)  but cannot figure
> out why it works there but not on this application.
>
> I don't know if its helpful but the full code is on GitHub here
>
> ---
>
> And I have the current (in Progress Version) on GitHub Pages Here
> -***
>
> Please Let me know if you need any more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know why but changing the schedule preview to

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import TaskBlock from "../taskblock";
import { ScheduleContext } from "../../contexts/schedulecontext";

const SchedulePreview = () => {
  const { tasks } = useContext(ScheduleContext);
  console.log(tasks);

  return (
    <div className="schedulepreviewcontainer">
      <div className="schedulepreview">
        <ul>
          {tasks.map((task) => {
            return <TaskBlock task={task} key={task.tID} />;
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default SchedulePreview;
```

Fixed it, basically just putting the taskblock elements into a UL.